# How to create folded edges with css

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

[Image i need to create with css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itVGg.png)

I cannot understand how should i create this with css.Please help

Comment: where you see the `rounded` in the image ?

Comment: There is a rounded folding edge if you see closely

Comment: needreciept.com/receiptGenerator8/public/home

Comment: see this page i need to create this black div

Comment: i have made this page using an image but that's not good enough as it is not responsive.need to create this with css.

Comment: so search how to do this with CSS ;)

Comment: couldn't find anything useful on this

Comment: 1 second search = https://bijaymagar.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/3d-css-ribbon/

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ribbon+css&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgqorlw9PZAhUHL1AKHTgzBCoQ_AUICigB&biw=1600&bih=794#imgrc=_

Comment: what you're looking for is not "rounded" borders, but "folded borders" or "ribbons". I know the feeling, it's hard to search when you don't know what you're searching for.

Answer (score -1):

in css you want to add class.
html:

css:
.rounded{border-radius:25px}

you can even set each corner to different radius
css:
rounded{25px 50px 30px 10px}

Answer (score -1):

What are you looking for is sort of ribbon effect.
First, you must use the ::before and ::after pseudo elements to create the two elements you need, the triangles, and place them absolutelly from the main content.
Then you have to transform the 2 elements in angles playing with borders.

For example:

```css
        .box {
            position:relative;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 10px auto 0;
            background-color: red;
        }
        .box::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: -10px;
            left: 0;
            border-width: 10px 10px 0px 0;
            border-color: transparent blue transparent transparent;
            border-style: solid;
        }
        .box::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: -10px;
            right: 0;
            border-width: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
            border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
            border-style: solid;
        }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Here you can find some examples on how triangles in css works:
[How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work?rq=1)